# Build an inverted index in distributed environment

Tags: elasticsearch, hbase, information-retrieval

What tools/libs/platforms would you use if you had to build a distributed inverted index from scratch? elasticseach (I need partial TF with dates constraints) only partially does what I need it, and thinking about building an inverted index using hbase, but wondering if there are some more sane choices (I will not fit all into memory, and will initially looking into caching).

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements still sound pretty vague to me, so some additional detail would be helpful in providing a better answer.

Solr Cloud may be a good option if you need support for faceting and fuzzy term matching. Solr Cloud is simply the distributed configuration of Solr. It's a bit more tedious to setup than elasticsearch but still a very powerful and popular tool.

If you're not already using HBase I'm not sure I'd recommend introducing it just for the sole purpose of creating an index.

Could probably give you a better answer if I understood your use case and current environment better.

Comment: Basically I need to track the changes in frequencies over time for some tokens (unigram and n-gram) and be able to incorporate this into the relevance formula. As my understanding is, you can not do this with Lucene (solr, elasticsearch).